# Write additionnals images in a tiff file without erasing existing images

Tags: python, image, tiff, python-imageio

What I'm actually doing is saving images in a tiff file, using `imageio.mimwrite()`. But in my script, I open and close the file several times, so it erases existing images before saving news images. I want to keep existing images in the tiff file, and just add new images without erasing the previous ones. I did not find anything in the documentation which can helps me.

I'm actually using this :
`imageio.mimwrite("example.tiff", image, format=".tiff")`

`image` is an array which contains arrays of integers, each array representing an image.

This code opens `example.tiff`, erase existing images (if they exist), and write news images. But I want to add like `open("file.txt", "a")` does.

Comment: You want to store several images in one tiff file?

Comment: Yes that's what I want at the end

Comment: Try [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/): `tifffile.imwrite(filename, image, append=True, metadata=None)`. I would avoid this approach if possible. Opening a TIFF file and seeking to the last IFD is relatively expensive...

Answer (score 1):

I made three differently sized TIFF images with **ImageMagick** like this for testing:

```
convert -size 640x480  xc:green             green.tif
convert -size 1024x768 xc:blue              blue.tif
convert -size 400x100 gradient:cyan-yellow  gradient.tif
```

Then I used the tool `tiffcp` which is distributed with the TIFF library and the `-a` option to append the blue and gradient image to the green one like this:

```
tiffcp -a blue.tif gradient.tif green.tif
```

If I then check the contents of `green.tiff` with **ImageMagick** `identify`, I see it looks correct:

```
magick identify green.tif
green.tif[0] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 16-bit sRGB 6.49355MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
green.tif[1] TIFF 1024x768 1024x768+0+0 16-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000
green.tif[1] TIFF 400x100 400x100+0+0 16-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

And if I preview the file, all three images are there with the correct sizes and colours:

[image]

So, I am suggesting you consider using `subprocess.run()` to shell out to `tiffcp`.

Comment: Incedentally the fact that you can simply `cat` TIFF files together is a hidden gem of the format – thanks @MarkSetchell for elucidating it here.

Comment: @cgohlke Thank you for alerting me to the error of my ways! I have updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: @fish2000 Please note I made an error somewhere and what I suggested was incorrect.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying – it was a neat idea for a moment there, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

With tifffile writing one page at a time (in the example a CTYX multipage), you can just write straight from a n-D array if you have enough RAM for it with tifffile.imwrite(filename,array)
https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/ :

```
import tifffile as tf
with tf.TiffWriter("filenametest.tiff",
                    #bigtiff=True,
                    #If you want to add on top of an existing tiff file (slower) uncomment below
                    #append = True,
                    imagej=False,) as tif:
    for time in range(rgb.shape[1]):
         tif.save(rgb[:,time,:,:].,
                #compress= 3,
                photometric='minisblack',
                metadata= None,
                contiguous=False,
            )
tif.close()
```

With python-bioformats:

https://pythonhosted.org/python-bioformats/

```
bioformats.write_image(pathname, pixels, pixel_type, c=0, z=0, t=0, size_c=1, size_z=1, size_t=1, channel_names=None)[source]
```

if you have:

- 4 time points with
- 3 color zstacks (11 Z's)
- with XY at 1024 pixels.
  with independent numpy arrays being [3,11,1024,1024] (one for each timepoint),
- 16bits,
  and named: a,b,c,d.

This should do the trick

```
import bioformats as bf
import numpy as np

#do something here to load a,b,c, and d

i=0
for t in [a,b,c,d]:
    for c in range(3):
        for z in range(11):
            #t here is the numpy array
            bf.write_image('/path/to/file.tiff' 
            , t
            , bf.PT_UINT16
            , c = c, z = z , t = i, size_c= 3, size_z=11, size_t=4
            )
    i+=1
```